# Change UI based on System Language - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, localization

I have an app and I want to support 2 languages. English and Greek.
I have already localised the whole app and everything works perfect except the UI.
I want to change images based on the system language user has. It works fine on simulator but when I use my real device the app changes its language except the images.

This is my code for the change.

```
let language = NSLocale.current.identifier

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupUI()
}

func setupUI() {

        if language == "el_US" {
            print(language)
            scanBtn.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "scanBtnGr"), for: .normal)
            detoxBtn.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "detoxGr"), for: .normal)
            bioBtn.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "bioBtn"), for: .normal)
            searchBtn.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "browseGr"), for: .normal)
            captureBtn.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "scanGr"), for: .normal)
            uploadBtn.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "uploadGr"), for: .normal)
        }else{
            print(language)
            scanBtn.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "scanBtn"), for: .normal)
            detoxBtn.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "detoxBtn"), for: .normal)
            bioBtn.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "bioBtn"), for: .normal)
            searchBtn.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "browseBtn"), for: .normal)
            captureBtn.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "scan"), for: .normal)
            uploadBtn.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "upload"), for: .normal)
        }
    }
```

I really don't know where is the problem because on the Simulator works perfect.

Comment: did you try to debug it? do you use breakpoints? you probably have different language than `el_US`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the way you set those images as below can help.

```
scanBtn.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: NSLocalizedString(key: "scanBtnGr", comment: ""), for: .normal)
```

In this way, you won't have to worry about the target language code as well. You can remove if statement and define corresponding names in `Localizable.strings` file.

Besides, if you change the language of your app without terminating the app and changing the device language, please make sure that `setupUI()` function gets invoked one more time after the language switch. `viewWillAppear` may be a suitable place for it.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. How am I going to define the images in Localizable.strings file.

Comment: Also I have to mention that these images are in the assets folder.

Comment: It's okay to have them in assets folder. For example, you need to have a line such as `"scanBtn" = "scanBtnGr";` in `Localizable.strings (Greek)`. Before that, you need to make sure that you set up localization properly. You can learn more about localization with this link. https://medium.com/lean-localization/ios-localization-tutorial-938231f9f881

Comment: It worked perfectly. Thank you. Also I didn't place the `setupUI` in the `viewWillAppear`. it works fine in the `viewDidLoad`.